# Split a data frame with multiple observations from 1 variable into multiple variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and would like to carry out some basic data analysis using stock market data obtained from the [internet](http://pages.swcp.com/stocks/). This data consists of 122573 different observations across 8 variables namely: Date, Ticker, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume for the day.

The problem is, after loading the data in R and running the "structured" command - str(), I obtained the following:

```
'data.frame':   122573 obs. of  1 variable:

$ X20090821.A.25.6.25.61.25.22.25.55.34758: Factor w/ 122573 levels "20090821,AA,12.64,12.73,12.49,12.56,338295",..: 499 998 1497 1996 2495 2994 3493 3992 4491 4990 ...
```

Please can someone show me how to split this data frame into 8 variables as required and label each variable column accordingly?

Thanks

Comment: Following the link, I see that the data are delimited by commas. Therefore, read it into R using `read.table()` with `sep=","`, then you will have a `data.frame` with eight columns.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you somehow read the data in a different way, but if I read it like this:

```
> df <- read.csv("path_to_file", header=FALSE)
```

The data is structured in as follows

```
> head(df)
        V1 V2    V3      V4     V5    V6    V7
1 20090821  A 25.60 25.6100 25.220 25.55 34758
2 20090824  A 25.64 25.7400 25.330 25.50 22247
3 20090825  A 25.50 25.7000 25.225 25.34 30891
4 20090826  A 25.32 25.6425 25.145 25.48 33334
5 20090827  A 25.50 25.5700 25.230 25.54 70176
6 20090828  A 25.67 26.0500 25.630 25.83 39694
```